# PHP password_verify not functioning with prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, bcrypt

I started using mysqli prepared statements.  Everything was working properly.  I posted to Code Review to see if there were any unforeseen errors or security issues.  Found here:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/194163/php-login-script

I updated my code as instructed, however I ran into a problem with password_verify.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
include('../include/sessions.php');

if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
  $select = "SELECT username, firstname, lastname, email, userlevel, `password` FROM users WHERE username = ?;";
  $stmt = $dbc->prepare($select);

  $stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['username']);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result();
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  if($row && password_verify($row['password'], $_POST['password']))
  {
    $_SESSION['user'] = $row;

    header("Location: ../cust/home.php");
    die;
  }
  else
  {
    echo "The username/password combination does not match our records.  Please try again.";
  }
}
?>
```

The above prepared statement executes accordingly.  I can return the username, firstname, lastname, etc... But the password is not matching even though I am entering it correctly.

The database password was hashed using bcrypt. I am not sure if that is playing a role in this error.

Since the password cannot be verified, it of course skips to the else and echoes that the password is incorrect.

Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: Switch the variables around. The description is `bool password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )`, so the POST password comes first, then the database result.

Comment: @aynber - Would you mind posting an answer so I can check this off as answered?

Comment: First of all, do you like to get hacked? I would never use a $_POST variable in a Query or something equivalent to data processing without trimming the input...

Comment: @YvanWatchman - Well, I started using prepared statement in an attempt to prevent hacking.  What is it that you are trying to suggest?  Should I cleanse the parameters, set it to a variable, then use the variable in the query?

Comment: @JohnBeasley indeed, clean the variable up by using for example htmlspecialchars() and/or trim(). PDO Prepare does not fix every hack attempt :P Saving it to a variable is a possible and to prevent SSRF hacking unsetting the variables after usage (including $_POST[]) is very useful !

Comment: @YvanWatchman - thank you, sir.  I will take this into consideration and clean up the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleartext password needs to come first, then the hashed password from the database, per the description of the function `bool password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )`

```
password_verify($_POST['password'], $row['password']))
```

Comment: So after converting my code to your suggestion, I am finding that now, I can enter any password, no matter right or wrong, and i can gain access to the site.  Thoughts?

Comment: That is very odd. You may want to echo out the values and the results of password_verify while testing, just to see what's going on.

Comment: Ok - I found the problem.  I was on the javascript side.  On me.  Thanks for your help.  Not sure why I was downvoted though, but thanks.